# Transformer secondary C.T. Label

Tags: transformer

Can anyone tell me what the “C.T.” Stands for in the Secondary Volts column (see pic) stands for? When I see that my mind thinks “current transformer” but this is not a current transformer in the sense that I think of them. I know that current gets “transformed” across any transformer but my understanding of a current transformer is on the order of a Window CT used to monitor motor current or line current in substation, etc.

[image: Stancor Transformers]

Image from [www.alliedelec.com/m/d/08507f560b87dc69b56b0077e6976f5f.pdf](https://www.alliedelec.com/m/d/08507f560b87dc69b56b0077e6976f5f.pdf).

Comment: Center tapped ? maybe

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Center-tapped. In this case it means that the secondary winding has two opposite phases and a middle connection.

Such a transformer looks like this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fQ5JFtm.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

For a 5V AC secondary transformer, the voltages are:

- V1 to V2: 5V AC
- V1 to Vct: 2.5V AC
- V2 to Vct: 2.5V AC

Comment: If you don't want to create schematics for the deaf you can add the 's', 'm' and 'l' suffix to the filename and Imgur will render it small, medium or large. e.g. 12345.jpg can be renamed to 12345m.jpg. I think there are a couple of other options but I can't remember them.

Comment: I am, visualizing, Garrett Morris...

Comment: I forgot to mention that I think you've got to undo the sizing to make the schematic editable again. There's no problem with images though.